# Install kernlab package on R

Tags: linux, r, suse

I'm trying to install kernlab package on R, but I got a whole bunch of error messages, near the end it says:

`g++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o kernlab.so brweight.o ctable.o cweight.o dbreakpt.o dcauchy.o dgpnrm.o dgpstep.o dprecond.o dprsrch.o dspcg.o dtron.o dtrpcg.o dtrqsol.o esa.o expdecayweight.o inductionsort.o kspectrumweight.o lcp.o misc.o msufsort.o solvebqp.o stringk.o stringkernel.o svm.o wkasailcp.o wmsufsort.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: * [kernlab.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package âkernlabâ
* removing â/usr/lib64/R/library/kernlabâ`

The downloaded source packages are in
        â/tmp/RtmpzLdUMp/downloaded_packagesâ
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making packages.html  ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("kernlab") :
  installation of package âkernlabâ had non-zero exit status

I suspect it has something to do gcc-fortran. I'm using SUSE 11 SP1, I have libgfortran43-4.3.4_20091019-47.1 installed, but i wasn't able to figure out how to install gcc-fortran with yast.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use SUSE but a little bit of searching suggests that you can get gcc-fortran from this page: http://software.opensuse.org/package/gcc-fortran